# connect ArcGIS server with different instances of oracle database

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

Is it possible for a development team to have personal oracle database instances, for testing purposes, connected with the same GIS server? 
In other words I want every user to work with his own data, but use the same services that are exposed in the ArcGIS for server.
I am going to use ArcSDE .

Comment: What level of ArcGIS Server do you have? [License Levels](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf)

Comment: ArcGIS for Server Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a service point at a different instance (or even user) depending on the connected user, but you could configure a proxy to point at different services.  This would require N, N+1, or N+2 services for each logical service (depending on whether you have test and production requirements as well). You'd probably be better off with personal *USER* data, not personal *INSTANCE* data, since the latter requires multiple Oracle instances, which gets pretty expensive very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a version scenario for the developers. Going off what Vince stated I don't think it's possible to use your mentioned workflow.

It would have to either be separate instances or some sort of version workflow/replication.

Comment: That would be an exceptionally inefficient implementation for versioning. Hideously inefficient. So far from best practice as to qualify for "worst possible practice." And I don't see any way versioning could be used for this purpose, either (default version is a property of a connection).

Comment: I agree. It wouldnt be pretty, but I was trying to think of other possible scenarios that might work.